# nestjs swagger-ui SSL_PROTOCOL_ERR on centos 7

Tags: https, swagger, nestjs, swagger-ui

When connecting to swagger from a local PC after npm start

API PATH : 'api'

`Request URL: http://localhost:11002/api/`

`Request URL: http://localhost:11002/api/swagger-ui-bundle.js`

swagger docs web opens normally!

---

I configured the same project on centos7.

API PATH : 'api'

`Request URL: http://10.62.130.54:11002/api/`

`Request URL: https://10.62.130.54:11002/api/swagger-ui-bundle.js`

swagger docs web does not open!!
=>> SSL PROTOCOL ERROR

Why are you trying with https?

thanks!!

### -
@nestjs/swagger@5.2.1
swagger-ui-express@4.5.0

Answer (score 1):

use localhost for domain (in your case, http://localhost:11002/api/), origins are assumed trustworthy when they use localhost resolution